# Letsencrypt installed by Certbot but https for iredadmin still insecure

Tags: email, certificate

Successfully installed letsencrypt certificate for two mail server domain on iredMail server.

```
root@mail:~# certbot certificates
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Found the following certs:



Certificate Name: mail.domain1.com
    Domains: mail.domain1.com
    Expiry Date: 2019-08-13 12:14:38+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain1.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain1.com/privkey.pem


Certificate Name: mail.domain2.com
    Domains: mail.domain2.com
    Expiry Date: 2019-08-08 19:13:41+00:00 (VALID: 85 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain2.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain2.com/privkey.pem

https://mail.domain2.com/iredadmin is secure, but

https://mail.domain1.com/iredadmin is insecure
```

Need help to diagnose; where should I check?

Comment: look at iRedMail doc  already On Debian/Ubuntu, FreeBSD and OpenBSD:
mv /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt{,.bak}       # Backup. Rename iRedMail.crt to iRedMail.crt.bak
mv /etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key{,.bak}     # Backup. Rename iRedMail.key to iRedMail.key.bak
ln -s /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt
ln -s /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com/privkey.pem /etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key

Comment: Already done for domain1 works for domain1.  If did the same to second domain2, will over-write domain1?

Comment: Please don’t let your question still over into comments.  If there is information that people need to know to be able to answer your question, you should [edit] it *into the question.*  And then use the formatting capabilities that are available.